# Characterization of free modules by morphisms' extensions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm trying to prove that if we have a subset $B$ of a module $M$, then $M$ is free with basis $B$ if and only if for every module $N$ and every function $\varphi\colon B \to N$, there is an unique morphism $f\colon M \to N$ which extends $\varphi $.

If we assume $M$ free with basis $B = (b_i)_{i\in I}$, every $m\in M$ writes uniquely as $m = \sum_{i\in I} r_ib_i$ for some almost-null sequence of scalars $(r_i)_{i\in I}$, and defining $f(m) = \sum_{i\in I} r_i \varphi(b_i)$ does the job.

I'm having trouble with the converse. I thought of taking the inclusion of $B$ in ${\rm span}(B)$, and extending it to $f\colon M \to {\rm span}(B)$, so that $f(m) \in {\rm span}(B)$, and: $$f(m) = \sum_{i\in I}r_i b_i = \sum_{i\in I} r_i f(b_i) = f\left(\sum_{i\in I} r_ib_i\right)$$ for some almost-null sequence of scalars $(r_i)_{i\in I}$, but I don't think that helps so much. And I would have to check that $B$ is linearly independent. Another idea is extending $\pi \colon B \to M/{\rm span}(B)$, but I'm unsure. Help?

Comment: "there is a morphism" -> "there is a unique morphism".

Comment: Ah, I forgot to write that! Sorry. But then the inclusion extends to the identity and I'm done. Thanks

Comment: Wait. This proves that $B$ spans $M$, but how can I see that $B$ is L.I.?

Comment: The proof I know proceeds by constructing the actual free module with basis $B$, and then proving that it is isomorphic to $M$ (since we get morphisms in both directions by the universal property).

Comment: OK, actually that's not necessary. For each $b \in B$, we define a function $\delta_b : B \to K$ (where $K$ is the commutative ring over which we are working) by $\delta_b\left(b\right) = 1$ and $\delta_b\left(c\right) = 0$ for all $c \neq b$. Extend this $\delta_b$ to a $K$-linear map $M \to K$. Now, if you have a linear dependency relation between the elements of $B$, then applying $\delta_b$ to it shows that the coefficient of $b$ in it is $0$, and this works for each $b \in B$.

Comment: Ah, I got it. Thanks a lot, this works nicely. You can upgrade that to an answer if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm turning darij's comment into an answer, since it solved my problem.

> For each $b \in B$ we definde a function $\delta_b\colon B \to K$ (where $K$ is the commutative ring over which we are working) by $\delta_b(b)=1$ and $\delta_c(b) = 0$ for all $c \neq b$. Extend this $\delta_b$ to a $K$-linear map $M \to K$. Now, if you have a linear dependency relation between the elements of $B$, then applying $\delta_b$ to it shows that the coefficiente of $b$ in it is $0$, and this works for each $b \in B$.

Comment: @PabloS.Ocal: Why should $K$ be a basis? And what is $R$?